# Modifying tuple element from the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a following dictionary as input:

```
my_dict[(1, 2)] = (3,4)
```

Now what I want to have convert it to is:

```
my_dict[(1,2)] = (3,40)
```

What is the best and efficient way to do this?

The dictionary itself is not very big...

I could probably do something like:

```
for (var1,var2),(var3,var) in my_dict.iteritems():
    del my_dict[(var1,var2)]
    my_dict[(var1,var2)] = (var3, var5)
```

but I don't think its right approach as I modify the dictionary in a loop.

Comment: You don't need to delete the key there.

Comment: As Lev indicated you don't need to delete keys, just assign new values. And when you are not adding or removing keys you can just use a for loop over the keys ( `for key in my_dict:` ). It would of course be different if you removed/added keys, then you would need something like `for key in my_dict[:]`.

Comment: @Anthon: You can't slice a dict. You'd need something like `for key in list(my_dict)` if you were adding or removing keys.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right that should be your example or `for key in mydict.keys()`, I was mixing code examples with walking over a list you are modifying.

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign directly to the key; no need to delete the key first.

You could loop over the dictionary, yielding keys (your tuples); no need to unpack these even:

```
for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = (my_dict[key][0], var5)
```

or include the values:

```
for key, (val1, _) in my_dict.iteritems():
    my_dict[key] = (val1, var5)
```

This unpacks *just* the value so you can reuse the first element. I've used `_` as the name for the second value element to document it'll be ignored in the loop.

Comment: `var3` comes from the key's existing value. You do need the values.

Comment: @user2357112: ah, indeed. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    my_dict={}
    my_dict[(1, 2)] = (3,4)

    for i,val in my_dict.items():

        my_dict[i]=(3,24)
    print my_dict

    #output {(1, 2): (3, 24)}
```

other way.

```
    for i in my_dict.keys():

        my_dict[i]=(3,24)
    print my_dict
```

also

```
for i in my_dict:

    my_dict[i]=(3,24)
print my_dict
```

Comment: Why `items`? All you need in the loop is the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
my_dict[(1, 2)] = (3,4)
my_Dict2={i:(j[0],j[1]*10) for i,j in my_Dict.items()}
```

But I'm not sure if this is what your looking for since 'var5' in your code snippet is not defined. However, if you need to modify a tuple, there is probably a better type to use.